# Running a loop to vary the number of samples

Tags: r, loops

I have set some initial parameters for the moments of the gamma and lognormal distribution and applied the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to obtain the p-value. My aim is to show a plot of p-values against N for varying N. Lets say between 5 and 1000. How would I achieve this?

```
mean <- 10
var <- 40
N <- 100
gamsample <- rgamma(N, shape=mean^2/var, rate=mean/var)
lnsample <- rlnorm(N, meanlog=log(mean)-log(1+mean^2/var)/2,
                          sdlog=sqrt(log(1+(mean^2/var))))

ks.test(gamsample, lnsample)$p.value
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sapply()`:

```
mean <- 10
var <- 40
myP <- function(N) {
  gamsample <- rgamma(N, shape=mean^2/var, rate=mean/var)
  lnsample <- rlnorm(N, meanlog=log(mean)-log(1+mean^2/var)/2,
                     sdlog=sqrt(log(1+(mean^2/var))))

  ks.test(gamsample, lnsample)$p.value
}
N <- 5:1000
sapply(N, myP)
```

Or (more secure) `vapply(N, myP, FUN.VALUE = 9.9)`.
If you want a dataframe as result you can do:

```
results <- data.frame(n=N, pval=sapply(N, myP))
```

For a plot @AndreElrico proposed in his (deleted) answer:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(results, aes(x=n,y=pval)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: Nitpicks: avoid dots in names, they mess with automatic S3 method registration. `sapply` is error-prone as its output type is unpredictable. Prefer `vapply` or `lapply` as appropriate.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I changed the names.

Comment: @jogo thank you for your answer, very educational. I have edited my question with an additional query. Not sure if I should ask another question because it's related to this but I would like to see your take on it.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275138/how-to-deal-with-op-asking-another-questions-after-answering-original-question ... so ask an new question and put a link to this one.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I should have included it within this question but thought of it afterwards.